# Which OS for Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian

Is Raspbian the best operating system for my PI? On the new out of the box OS thing there are many other options for things to download, which one do I choose?

Comment: You and your mates have been posting a lot of bad content. Please read the [help] and familiarize yourself with what types of questions we consider on topic. Copying each other's answers is a no-no and posting non-answers is also unacceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raspbian is perfect for beginners to the raspberry pi.

- It is easy to set-up and use
- There is lots of support available on-line for it, as most people are using it.
- It is based on Debian   which is a widley used OS.
- It is specifically designed to run on the    raspberry pi.

However it all depends on what you want to use your Pi for, raspbian is great for general use. But if you were looking to do something more specific, like set up a media centre you might want to use RaspBMC